# Create your own style

Tags: package-writing

I know this question has been asked many times, but I could not find a good answer for my question, yet...

I wanted to develop my own thesis style i.e. `\usepackage{harthesis}`, which I did, but when I compile it, I got an error saying `harthesis.sty` is not found...

What is the easiest and best way to create your own thesis style? I am sure this question would be very helpful for many people.

These are part of my developed, but not limited to thesis styles:

1. `\permanentaddress`
2. `\examiners`
3. `\convocation`

and so on..

These were intended to be my title page and other university requirements before I even start writing my Intro..

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell from this scarce information. Do you have a `\ProvidesPackage{harthesis}` statement in your package?

Comment: Generally speaking, every university has a template for thesis. You need to double check that  first before creating your own style.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments! The University indeed has requirements, which I already have read them, but they do not specify any requirements for using LaTeX.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Creating a package means giving it a proper license, so others are able to use it. But that also means, you are in charge of maintaining your own package and respond to bug reports.

Comment: @Johannes_B No. Creating a package requires no licence so long as you don't intend to publish it anywhere. And you won't get any bug reports except from yourself.  I'm sure many of us have a few private packages floating around.   So if you publish a package somewhere it's a good plan to have a licence but otherwise it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I fully agree with Alan Munn: License issues are totally secondary in this case. The main issue that the `.sty` file is either not found at all or does not work due to syntax etc. errors

Comment: Thank you guys for your thoughts! I just wanted to create my own style like I tried to describe very briefly in my question as I do believe the custom LaTeX styles, let's say when you want to add extra things to your document depending on requirements and goals it get's a little bit tricky and complicated. In my case, I have to follow certain standards/requirements (internal-university) for the theses so it is/was impossible for me to get very first pages with titles and personal information. I got stuck right away so just decided to share with my problems and thoughts! That is it...